# How to make this function suitable for Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I have a function that I want to Fourier transform, 
$$f(t) = A e^{-t/\tau} \sin(\omega_{0}(1 - \alpha e^{-t/\tau}) t) \text{,}$$
but it turns out the software I am using (Mathematica) really struggles with this. I was wondering if anyone can see a way of tidying up this expression, perhaps with some integral forms so that I can go ahead and take the FT of this.

Comment: Well for positive $\tau \ll 1$ and small enough , your function can be approximated as $f(t)=Ae^{-t/\tau}\sin(\omega_0 t)$. Without that approximation, I'm not sure if any closed form exists. But anyway, I don't think your Fourier transform would make sense, at least in the usual way, because your function diverges for large $|t|$ when $t<0$.

Comment: So I can add the constraint that $t > 0$, as from a physical perspective it is time. $\tau$ is always $\tau > 0$ as again, it is an actual time constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long and short of this is; you can't. The best thing to do is to approximate the exponential component with a series expansion of $e^{x}$, or, use the solutions for the chirped oscillating wave.